# Clear the list after submission Flutter Provider

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I'm having a could of **TextFormField** with a **ListView.Builder** & using **Provider** as statemanagement. Upon submission of the Form i was able to add it to the list but only the **Text** in the **TextFormField** is getting cleared but not the list.

Did try by using `.clear()` but then the whole data was not getting added.

```
Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              widget.title.isEmpty
                  ? Text(
                      'Add Recipe',
                      style: TextStyle(color: ColorConstants.kDarkColor, fontSize: 25.sp),
                    )
                  : Text(
                      'Edit Recipe',
                      style: TextStyle(color: ColorConstants.kDarkColor, fontSize: 25.sp),
                    ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration:
                    const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Title', hintText: 'Enter Title'),
                controller: titleController..text = widget.title,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Description', hintText: 'Enter Description'),
                controller: descriptionController..text = widget.description,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Flexible(
                      child: TextFormField(
                    controller: stepController,
                    decoration:
                        const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Step', hintText: 'Add Steps'),
                  )),
                  TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        context.read<NewDishController>().addStep(DishSteps(
                            'Step ${NewDishController().stepNumber}',
                            stepController.text));
                        stepController.clear();
                      },
                      child: const Text("ADD"))
                ],
              ),
              const RecipeSteps(),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  TextButton(
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                      child: const Text('CANCEL')),
                  TextButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        if (titleController.text.isNotEmpty) {
                          context.read<NewDishController>().addDish(DishModel(
                              titleController.text,
                              descriptionController.text,
                              NewDishController().stepsList));
                        } else {
                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                              const SnackBar(content: Text('Title is empty')));
                        }
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                      child: const Text('CONFIRM')),
                ],
              )
            ],
          )
```

And this is the ChangeNotifier

```
class NewDishController extends ChangeNotifier {

  late String _title;
  String get title => _title;

  late String _description;
  String get description => _description;

  int _stepNumber = 1;
  int get stepNumber => _stepNumber;

  List<DishSteps> _stepsList = [];
  UnmodifiableListView<DishSteps> get stepsList => UnmodifiableListView(_stepsList);
  List<DishModel> _dishesList = [];
  UnmodifiableListView<DishModel> get dishesList => UnmodifiableListView(_dishesList);

  addStep(DishSteps step) {
    _stepsList.add(step);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  addDish(DishModel dish) {
    _dishesList.add(dish);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  stepIncrement() {
    _stepNumber++;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  stepDecrement() {
    _stepNumber--;
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

This is the ListView

```
class RecipeSteps extends StatelessWidget {
  const RecipeSteps({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    NewDishController dishController = Provider.of<NewDishController>(context);

    return ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: dishController.stepsList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Card(
          elevation: 8,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Consumer<NewDishController>(builder: (_, listener, __) => RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                text: listener.stepsList[index].step+". ",
                style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
                children: <TextSpan>[
                  TextSpan(text: listener.stepsList[index].description, style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                ],
              ),
            )),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you also post your ListView? Is it wrapped in a `Consumer`? It looks like it is not getting notified.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the whole `ListView` with `Consumer<NewDishController>` not just an item and use the length of that to build a list.